# Putty renders backtick as a circumflex

Tags: linux, putty, gentoo, charset

When using Putty to connect to a Gentoo UTF-8 machine, backticks are represented as an "a circumflex": `â`

Putty makes a quote into an "a circumflex".

How to I prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 0):

**putty shows quotes as `a` with a hat**

Putty sometimes has problems converting char sets, you have to fiddle around with your character set translation on received data.

**In Putty config, go here:**

[image]

1. In putty, go to the configuration, click the "Window" item.
2. Click the "Translation" item.
3. There will be a dropdown box that says: `Received data assumed to be in which character set` Set this to UTF-8.  Or if it's already UTF-8, try one of the ISO-8859 varients.
4. Save the settings and open a new terminal.
5. The `a circumflex` is properly rendered as a back tick now.

**For the curious, why does this happen?**

http://www.downtowndougbrown.com/2012/02/fix-for-putty-displaying-a-instead-of-quotes-when-connected-to-a-linux-machine/

Comment: If it's already UTF-8, then it is usually best to make the *other end* (i.e. the Gentoo box) UTF-8 as well. As someone speaking a language with accented letters, all my experiences with ISO-8859 have been horrible.